# Writing CSV file VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, csv, save

i'm just having troubles with a CSV file saving code in VB.NET

I'm trying to save a CSV file that will be read in a DataGridView. I just made the "reading" code, it works perfectly! What's wrong with saving of the file?

```
Public Class Builder

Sub Create_Records()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To Manager.Grid.Rows.Count - 1
        Manager.Grid.Rows.Add("ciao;", "comestai")
    Next
End Sub

Sub Write()
    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\MyPCBuilder")) Then 
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\MyPCBuilder")
    End If
  
    Dim Write As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\MyPCBuilder\builds.csv")
    For i = 0 To Manager.Grid.Rows.Count - 1
        Text = ""
        For j = 0 To 1
            If Text = Text & Manager.Grid.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value & ";" Then
            Else
                Text = Text & Manager.Grid.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value
            End If
        Next
        Write.WriteLine(Text)
    Next
    Write.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btn_Confirm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Confirm.Click
    Create_Records()
    Write()
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You havent debugged this have you?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 1):

The If-statement in your  inner loop is wrong. The `Then` part is empty and the condition is strange. Since you have only 2 columns, simply write

```
For i = 0 To Manager.Grid.Rows.Count - 1
    Text = Manager.Grid.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & ";" & Manager.Grid.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
    Write.WriteLine(Text)
Next
```

If you want to keep this inner loop (in case you have more columns or a variable number of columns), test for the index instead (outer loop not shown)

```
Text = ""
For j = 0 To 1
    If j > 0 Then
        Text = Text & ";"
    End If
    Text = Text & Manager.Grid.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value
Next
```